# How to include multiple directories to search header files in C preprocessor

Tags: c

I am using `cpp -Idir_name` command to preprocess the source file. In `dir_name` I have header files included that need to be used for preprocessing.

I want to add multiple directories that can be searched for header files. How can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can have multiple `-I` directives, e.g.

```
cpp -Ifoo/bar -Ifoo/blech -I../baz ...
```